# Insert events with google calendar API into multiple calendars for multiple users

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

As I already read, google calendar API will need authorization for each calendar you will need to insert events...

My needs : Beeing able to insert events for multiple users without having to wait for users to authorize before the insertions...

(Some kind of batch export will call multiple times the insert method for several users)

I tried inserting for one user and needed to authorize before the API can work...

Is there any way to bypass user authorization ?

Is there any kind of supervisor account to do so ?

Is there any kind of google paid service who can handle this task ?

Answer (score 0):

> As I already read, google calendar API will need authorization for each calendar you will need to insert events...

Google calendar api will need authorization to the user who owns the calendar. You get access to all of a users calendars. So if you want access to 5 calendars and they are owned by a single user only that user need authorize your application.  However if you want access to 5 calendars owned by different users then they will need all authorize your application.

> My Need : Insert events for multiple users without having to wait for users to authorize before the insertions...

Google calendar data is private user data if you want access to a users Google calendar you need to ask for their consent. There is no way around this.

> Is there any way to bypass user authorization ? Is there any kind of supervisor account to do so ?

Not unless the accounts are on google workspace, in which case the admin of the workspace domain you can configure a service account with domain wide delegation to access the users accounts.  This will not work with a standard Google gmail domain account.

Comment: Thank you @Linda ! Very useful informations !

Comment: please, is Google Workspace some kind of enterprise edition ? I mean... the final user will probably have gmail entreprise account and will not use his personnal gmail account... Would it be in this case possible to have one access for all users and once for all ?

Comment: Check - https://workspace.google.com/  if it is then the admin can set it up so you can access all the users on the domain.